# Button and label are not shown in the iOS app using Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to write a hello world app on Xcode but I have two errors
The first error message is *DTAssetProviderService could not start DTXConnection with Simulator 'iPhone 5'. Check the system log for errors.* but I still can run the app but when I run the app on simulatior it does not show the button and label I put in the app. It shows just a screen of the app. Here is my codes in the app for `ViewController.h` and `ViewController.m`

`ViewController.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {

IBOutlet UILabel *hellolabel;

}

- (IBAction)button1:(id)sender;

@end
```

`ViewController.m`

```
 #import "ViewController.h"


 @implementation ViewController


 -(IBAction)button1:(id)sender {

   hellolabel.text = @"hello world";
 }



 - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
 [ super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

And here is my main.storyboard interface

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYKNU.jpg)

Comment: can you pls add a screenshot of your storyboard here. This is probably because of the not setting the constraint correctly.

Comment: I have just added the pic of my storyboard

Answer (score 0):

put your button and label in top - left side in your storyboard interface builder for now and you can see it on simulator.

It is because of different screen sizes, size classes and autolayout.

You should learn `autolayout`, after you can set constraints to your components and this kind of problem will not be faced.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably in your main.storyboard, which you haven't linked below. More than likely, as others have said, you've mucked up your constraints.

On your main.storyboard delete any constraints and move all your buttons to the left most side. Also make sure that your width and height read wAny hAny, as that is the best to use for any screen.